# Simplify a complex expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{a - b\omega }{a\omega^2 -b}-\omega^2= ....$$
$$a) 3i$$
$$b)+or- \sqrt{3}$$
$$c) -3$$
$$d) 3$$
My turn :
$$A = \frac{a-b\omega - a\omega^4 +b\omega}{a\omega^2 -b}$$
$$=\frac{a-a\omega -b\omega +b\omega^2}{a\omega^2 -b}$$
$$\frac{(1-\omega)(a-b\omega}{a\omega^2 -b}$$
I stopped here without getting any answer matches with the choices ?

Comment: is $\omega \neq  1$ a cube root of unity?

Comment: Yes $\omega $is a cube root of 1

Answer (score 1):

$a-b\omega=\omega(a\omega^2-b)$

Comment: And the expression is equal to $\omega-\omega^2$, which is $\sqrt{3}i$ or $-\sqrt{3}i$. None of the options is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is $$\frac{a-bw-w^2(aw^2-b)}{aw^2-b}=…$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{a - b\omega }{a\omega^2 -b}-\omega^2= \frac{\omega(a\omega^2 - b)}{a\omega^2 -b}-\omega^2=\omega-\omega^2$$

$\omega-\omega^2 = \frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}= \frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}-(-1-i\sqrt{3})}{2}=\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}+1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}=\frac{2i\sqrt3}{2}=\boxed{i\sqrt3}$

Similary if we consider value of $\omega = \frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2} \& \omega^2 = \frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ then this would simplyfy to $\boxed{-i\sqrt3}$

$\therefore$ possible answers are $\boxed{\bf{\pm i\sqrt3}}$.

Comment: Do you mean that there is no correct choice ?@Vineet Kumar

Comment: You can put the value of $\omega$ in the exp. and find out this is equal to $\pm\sqrt{3}i$

Comment: @HussienMohamed, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Its okay but i think $\omega = \frac{-1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ Only @Vineet Kumar

Comment: you can take any one of them as $\omega$. so none of your options match I guess.

Comment: Thank you , i have another question if you have a minute :the amplitude of $$z=(1-\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta}$$ is .....@Vineet Kumar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94190/discussion-between-vineet-kumar-and-hussien-mohamed).